# OpenNETCF: is it free to use?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, opennetcf

I downloaded all the OpenNETCF dlls. Is it free? Or will it stop working after a year?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean the [Smart Device Framework](https://github.com/ctacke/sdf) (migrated from [Codeplex](http://opennetcf.codeplex.com)), then yes the binaries are free to use and distribute.  There is no limitation in features or time on them for any edition, including the free Community Edition.

If you mean any of our other products or libraries (we've got quite a few), then you'll have to be a bit more specific.

Comment: thanks for the help, from where i can download any Documentation ? i cant find in the OpenNETCF website any

Comment: Hi, I'm wonder if I can use this framework in a console application to launch a WP7 application in emulator ... any thoughts ? thanks

Comment: @Paul - doubtful. The SDF is a set of assemblies designed to run *on a device*.  If you need something to help automate the emulator on the PC, I belive Justin Angel has done some work that might be of use.

Comment: @ctacke: thanks; indeed Justin blog posts helped me a lot in the process of automate the emulator on a PC.

Comment: @ctacke Please update the link for documentation. The given one is not working.

Comment: @ctacke: OpenNETCF is fantastic (great job Chris)...but documentation link still broken.

Comment: @alainD: restored the link

Comment: @ctacke: Still getting HTTP 404 on your link in the comment from 2011-01-18. Is the documentation link URL different?

Comment: @ctacke, great job on the lib! Stupid question - how do I download the installer from git?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the CodePlex project, it is open source. I have not looked at the license, but it will not magically stop working.